# smoothScrollToPosition by using getLastVisiblePosition

Tags: android, expandablelistview, smooth-scrolling

for ExpandableListView, there are 20 rows for current visible screen, and the getLastVisiblePosition gives me a correct value. However, when there is 1 item is expanded, the getLastVisiblePosition gives me 24 because that item contains 4 extra row. it is wrong because row 24 is no long visible. how can i fix that?

Also, assuming getLastVisiblePosition gives me a correct value. 
How can i make the 21st to be the first visible row by using smoothScrollToPosition(). 
i was trying very hard to solve it but still no luck.
thank you all.